# How to make Javascript code run in Phoenix?

Tags: javascript, phoenix-framework

So I am having a hard time making Javascript written in app.js actually work. This is what I have done so far:

First thing I did was write the code into the app.js file and hope it would work.

**App.js**

```
import "deps/phoenix_html/web/static/js/phoenix_html"

const selectSort = document.getElementById("sort");
console.log("Herp");
const sortEntities = () => {
  const sortvalue = selectSort.value;
  const entities = document.querySelectorAll(".entitiy");
  const sortedEntities = entities.sort((a, b) =>
     a.querySelector(`.${sortvalue}`).textContent > a.querySelector(`.${sortvalue}`).textContent);
     document.querySelector(".entitiy-list").innerHTML = sortedEntities;
};

selectSort.addEventListener("onChange", sortEntities);
```

Now I tried accessing the selectSort variable through console but I get undefined. I discovered that the app.js is never loaded in since I run windows and it could be fixed by adding another line in the autoRequire.

**brunch-config.js**

```
<---SNIPPET-->
  modules: {
    autoRequire: {
      "js/app.js": ["web/static/js/app"],
      "js\\app.js": ["web/static/js/app"] <-- The line added
    }
  },
<---SNIPPET-->
```

Now that the app.js file finally loads properly I get an error with the phoenix_html import.

**Error**

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "deps/phoenix_html/web/static/js/phoenix_html" from "web/static/js/app"
```

Even if I remove the import the variable will still not load properly when i type it into the console and the code never executes, while console.log message is executed. What am I missing? If I try write the code in the console window it works fine.

The project itself is quite old, probably from like November, so i might not be running the newest "phoenix template". Not sure if there are some known issue to this related there, i tried looking around. I even have "Programming Phoenix" but there wasn't much about making Javascript run there.

Comment: Did you run `mix deps.get` then `mix compile` before? You should make sure the phoenix_html is in `./deps/` first

Comment: Updating Phoenix from 1.0 to 1.1.2 seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My project used Phoenix 1.0 which had known issues with Windows and making Javascript execute properly. I upgraded to 1.1.2 and now everything works fine.